Finding the count of index in array of
How to find whether an array of string has only one index? I am trying with below piece of code but it is throwing index out of bound exception while the string contain only one letter.
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String initials = null;
        String name = "P";
        String[] breakdown = name.trim().split(" ");
        System.out.println("Length::: " + breakdown.length);
        if (breakdown.length == 1) {
            initials = (name.charAt(0) + "" + name.charAt(1)).toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("Initial if::: " + initials);
        } else if (breakdown.length > 1) {
            initials = (breakdown[0].charAt(0) + "" + breakdown[breakdown.length - 1].charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("Initial else::: " + initials);
        }
    }
}

While giving a single letter for name it should proceed and show the single character.

For future reference:  In addition to code, it is better that questions of this type include an exact copy of the error message. That should be as text, not as an image. Use text copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy. It also helps to show at least one example. Each example should show input, expected output, and actual output if there is any.

If the string contains only one character then charAt(1) is going to throw IndexOutOfBoundsException. Maybe you need to check the length of the string before calling name.charAt(1)?

This is pretty easy. You already have an array of words. Just loop over it and retrieve only the first letter from each word.
public static String getInitials(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.trim().split("\\s+"))
                 .map(part -> part.charAt(0))
                 .map(Character::toUpperCase)
                 .map(String::valueOf)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining());
}


Demo
public static void main(String... args) {
    String initials = getInitials("George Walker Bush");
    System.out.format("Length::: %s\n", initials.length());
    System.out.format("Initial::: %s\n", initials);
}

Output:
Length::: 3
Initial::: GWB


Since the very first operation of this solution is a regex operation, it begs the question whether all this subsequent stuff is needed, when the regex engine can do it in the first place, i.e. return str.replaceAll("\\s*\\b(\\w)\\S*", "$1").toUpperCase();

Yep, we can do it within one regexp expression

I think that the problem here is that you're trying to access the second character of a string when it might not exist and that causes to throw the exception.
Try changing the :
breakdown.length() == 1
to
breakdown.length() > 0
and the
name.charAt(1)
to
name.charAt(0)
This should fix your out of bound problem!

Like the questioner, you are confusing the array length (breakdown.length) with the string lengths (name.length() or breakdown[…].length())
